# Correct use of mclapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am experimenting with `mclapply` but without much luck. What I am wanting to do in this example is create a dataframe, split each row of that into a list, convert each list element to a vector and then take the mean of each list element (vector). I think it runs ok but the code using mclapply doesn't appear to engage any of additional cores. Am I using it correctly?

I am using a Mac.

```
library(parallel)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(10000)))
list <- split(df,seq(nrow(df)))

# apply
system.time({
list <- lapply(list, as.numeric)
list_means <- lapply(list, mean)
})

# mclapply
numberOfCores <- detectCores()
system.time({
  list <- mclapply(list, as.numeric, mc.cores = numberOfCores)
  list_means <- mclapply(list, mean, mc.cores = numberOfCores)
})
```

Comment: You're right - apologies. I don't normally make such a silly naming error, but wasn’t thinking. In any case - what am I missing - I get `length(list) == 10000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your work actually happens in the `split()` function, which reorganizes a list by columns (a data frame is a list by columns) to a list by rows. The subsequent `lapply()` and `mclapply()` are too fast to notice the difference. Try the following

```
library(parallel)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(1000, rnorm(10000)))

# apply
system.time({
  list_means3 <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) mean(as.numeric(df[i, ])))
})

# mclapply
numberOfCores <- detectCores()
system.time({
  list_means4 <- mclapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) mean(as.numeric(df[i, ])), mc.cores = numberOfCores)
})
```

where the access into `df` rows is parallel. I get the following times for `lapply()`

```
   user  system elapsed 
 21.644   0.049  21.719
```

and for `mclapply()`

```
   user  system elapsed 
 31.686   0.973   3.212
```

on an M3 mac.

Comment: Thanks, that takes (elapsed) 65 sec and 13 sec using lapply and mclapply, respectively on a 2017 iMac Pro. I have to say that I don't really understand the difference about whether you're doing an operation on a column or a row - it's still a vector of numbers. The main difference that I can see with what you've done is that lapply is working on a dataframe on the fly, rather than having converted it to a list in a prior step. Is that where parallelisation can be used? I assumed applying a function to list elements themselves would also benefit. Clearly, there are things I don't understand.

Comment: As you say, it is a vector of numbers. But today's machines have a hierarchy of memories (registers, several levels of cache, etc., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy) which are managed by bringing contiguous blocks from lower (larger and higher latency memories). If your operation only needs one contiguous block of memory, it's lightning fast. If it needs non-contiguous chunks, it can take many such blocks and transport from slower memories. Access by rows in a large-enough column contiguous vector is slow.

Comment: The difference is that the most time-expensive operation of accessing data (moving across memory hierarchy) in non-contiguous order is parallel in my code and it is serial in your code. The memory hierarchy movement is always in fixed-size contiguous blocks so the same data actually ends up moved several times.